# problem installing ubuntu 16.10 from iso

Tags: system-installation, virtualization, vmware, 16.10

problem installing ubuntu 16.10 from iso
 keep getting this message

[image: errors while installing]

This is a Virtual Machine, using VMWare

Comment: Can you please provide more information?  For example, are you booting from a USB drive, or DVD ROM? Have you burned the ISO correctly to the DVD, or written it to the USB using the correct tools?  What method have you followed to install it, the official Ubuntu method? Or a tutorial?  Are you using a Laptop or PC?  These kinds of things are really helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Thats not an error from the Ubuntu boot disk.

That's the PXE boot message.

It means that your boot order is not allowing the computer to boot from the Disk first, but instead is trying to boot from the network.

I'd suggest changing the boot order in your BIOS.

Alternatively, most computers in recent years have a key you can hit during boot that will offer you a boot menu.

Most frequently, it's the `F12` key.

Comment: Tried it, moved vmware virtual scsi hard drive to start
tried moving network to buttom
both solutions didn't help

Comment: I see, so this is VMWare, and not a physical machine.  Have you spoken with VMWare and their support groups?  This sounds like w Virtual Machine configuration issue to me, nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In Virtual Machine Settings make sure that the DVD is "connect at power on", "use ISO image file" pointing to your ISO.

Optionally, in the `.vmx` file, insert

```
bios.bootDelay = "2000"
```

to give you two seconds to press the Escape key to show the boot menu.

Comment: connected and connected at power on, and used iso image file, but the problem keeps repeating itself